# Application.Match Not matching numbers - Am I missing an integer command/call?

Tags: excel, vba

I need an macro that finds numbers for me after I put them, I found this code on this site but its doesnt work for number or larger words. I know I am missing a integer command somewhere but cant figure out - Any help is much appreciated!

Example of what works

```
Cat
Dog 
Hat
```

Example of what doesn't work

```
Combination 
238828810181782
V8238182HTC1822
#1dad4482828DDD
```

The way this works is, You scan for example barcodes from a product and it creates a list. Then you press a button, and it asks you input the barcode and it looks for the barcode in the list and tells you its been recorded. It works for short words but nothing longer than that or numbers.

```
 Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim MatchRow As Variant
Dim code As Variant
Dim matchedCell As Range

code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")

' verify that there is a successful match in the searched range
If Not IsError(Application.Match(code, Range("C2:C8"), 0)) Then
    MatchRow = Application.Match(code, Range("C2:C8"), 0) '<-- get the row number 
    Set matchedCell = Range("C" & MatchRow + 1) '<-- set the range (add 1 row since you are starting from row 2)
    matchedCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Now

    'option 2: without setting the range
    Range("C" & MatchRow).Offset(1, 2).Value = Now  
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: All combination work for /me in Excel2013....

Comment: Nothing wrong here (though code could maybe use some re-work) - are you sure the values are being scanned correctly?

Comment: I am using Excel 2016 and I just tried this number 7383891782 nothing happens - I set up a button as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the scanned barcode value only in column C?  Are you trying to update the cell two columns to the right and one row down with the current date/time?

This should get you close.

Edit: added LookIn/LookAt based on Tim and Ben's comments.  Change xlWhole to xlPart if you only need to find part of the string.

```
Sub test2()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim code As String
    
    code = InputBox("Please scan a barcode and hit enter if you need to")
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns("C:C").Find(What:=code, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Offset(1, 2).Value = Now
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this later!

Comment: When using `Find()` it's good practice to always specify `lookat` otherwise you're not sure if you're matching on partial values

Comment: ^ and `LookIn` too. More in the Remarks section in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Comment: Jeremy,  Tim, thanks,  it appears to be working. Will record a video of what happens.  Thank you all for the help!

Comment: And now, it doesn't work. Will have to record a video and show it you guys later today. Might be the excel I am using here